# How can I reference an exported typescript class in my JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, requirejs

I have a JavaScript file that is going to upload a file to Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  This JavaScript file references another JavaScript file via RequireJS.  The JavaScript file it references was compiled from several Typescript files.  The Typescript files set up a model to store the data to upload as well as the logic to interact with the Dynamics API.  I have read through the Typescript/RequireJS documentation as well as several related SO questions, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the define statement in RequireJS to work correctly so that I can use my model & Dynamics API logic from my JavaScript file.  Am I correctly exporting my classes from Typescript?  Am I correctly defining my import in JavaScript?

### Model.ts

```
export class ExpenseTransaction extends ModelBase {

    public Field1: string;
    public Field2: number;
    .
    .
    .

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    toJSON(): any {
        let json = {
            "ccseq_Field1@odata.bind": this.Connection + "(" + this.Field1 + ")",
            "ccseq_Field2": this.Field2, 
             .
             .
             .               
        };

        return json;

    }

}
```

### WebAPI.ts

```
import * as Model from './Model';

export class ExpenseTransaction extends APIBase {

constructor() {
    super();
}

ConvertToEntity = (data: Array<Object>): Array<Model.ExpenseTransaction> => {
    let result: Array<Model.ExpenseTransaction> = new Array<Model.ExpenseTransaction>();
    for (let i: number = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        let newRecord: Model.ExpenseTransaction = new Model.ExpenseTransaction();

        newRecord.Field1 = data[i]["_Field1_value"];
        newRecord.Field2 = data[i]["ccseq_Field2"];

        result[i] = newRecord;
    }
    return result;
}

Get(): Promise<{}> {
    let expenses: Array<Model.ExpenseTransaction>;
    let self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.ExpenseTransaction,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: (data: any): void => {resolve(self.ConvertToEntity(data.value));},
            error: (data: any) => { reject(data.status); }
        });
    });
};

Create(expense: Model.ExpenseTransaction): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.Connection,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(expense.toJSON()),
            success: (data: any): void => {resolve(data.value);},
            error: (data: any) => {reject(data.status);}
        });
    });
};
}
```

### Compiled Typescript

```
define("CCSEQ/Model", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

    class ExpenseTransaction extends ModelBase {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
        toJSON() {
            let json = {
                "ccseq_Field1@odata.bind": this.Connection + "(" + this.Field1 + ")",
                "ccseq_Field2": this.Field2
            };
            return json;
        }
    }
    exports.ExpenseTransaction = ExpenseTransaction;

define("CCSEQ/WebAPI", ["require", "exports", "CCSEQ/Model"], function (require, exports, Model) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

    class ExpenseTransaction extends APIBase {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.ConvertToEntity = (data) => {
                let result = new Array();
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let newRecord = new Model.ExpenseTransaction();
                    newRecord.Field1 = data[i]["_Field1_value"];
                    newRecord.Field2 = data[i]["Field2"];
                    result[i] = newRecord;
                }
                return result;
            };
        }
        Get() {
            let expenses;
            let self = this;
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.ExpenseTransaction,
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: (data) => { resolve(self.ConvertToEntity(data.value)); },
                    error: (data) => { reject(data.status); }
                });
            });
        }
        ;
        Create(expense) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.Connection,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(expense.toJSON()),
                    success: (data) => { resolve(data.value); },
                    error: (data) => { reject(data.status); }
                });
            });
        }
        ;
    }
    exports.ExpenseTransaction = ExpenseTransaction;
```

### JavaScript.js

```
    requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        '../CCSEQ.Library': ['CCSEQ/Model']
    }
})

define(["require", "../jquery-3.1.1", "../papaparse.min", "CCSEQ/Model"], function (require, jquery, Papa, Model) {
    "use strict"; 
    $(document).ready(() => {
        //$("#loading").hide();
        setupHandlers();
    });
    function setupHandlers() {
        "use strict";
        $("#csv-file").change((e) => {
            //$("#loading").show();
            let file = e.target.files[0];
            if (!file) {
                return;
            }
            Papa.parse(file, {
                complete: (results) => {
                    ImportExpenseTransaction(results.data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    function ImportExpenseTransaction(data) {
        let importData = new Array();
        data.forEach((expense) => {
            let newRecord = new Library.Model.ExpenseTransaction();
            newRecord.Field1 = expense["Field1"];
            newRecord.Field2 = expense["Field1"];
            importData.push(newRecord);
        });
        let expenseTransactionAPI = new ExpenseTransaction();
        expenseTransactionAPI.Create(importData[0]).then(() => { console.log("success"); }).catch(() => { console.log("failure"); });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have a module defined for `../CCSEQ.Library` as that may be the file name that you have chosen, but the only id's in there are `CCSEQ/Model` and `CCSEQ/WebAPI`

Usually in AMD there would be a single module per file, but can be told to map multiple modules to a single file using some extra config (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles)

```
requirejs.config({
  bundles: {
    'js/CCSEQ.Library': ['CCSEQ/Model', 'CCSEQ/WebAPI']
  }
})
```

where `js/CCSEQ.Library` is path to a js file relative to the baseUrl (i've assumed your compiled TS is at  `/js/CCSEQ.Library.js` - substitute for your real path, minus the `.js` extension)

You would then require the modules themselves directly, which would use the lookup to load the correct parent file

```
require(["../jquery-3.1.1", "../papaparse.min", "CCSEQ/Model",  "CCSEQ/WebAPI"], (jquery, Papa, Model, WebAPI) {
  const myModel = new Model.ExpenseTransaction()
  const myAPI = new WebAPI. ExpenseTransaction()
})
```

Alternatively if you want to access via a single Library module, you will need to add another typescript module to export them...

Library.ts

```
import * as Model from './Model'
import * as WebAPI from './WebAPI'
export default { Model, WebAPI }
```

This should create a module `CCSEQ/Library`
If you were to output your compiled TS to `CCSEQ/Library.js` relative to the RequireJS baseUrl you should simply be able to use it directly without extra config, otherwise do the mapping config like before

```
requirejs.config({
  bundles: {
    'js/CCSEQ.Library': ['CCSEQ/Library']
  }
})

require(["../jquery-3.1.1", "../papaparse.min", "CCSEQ/Library"], (jquery, Papa, Library) {
  const myModel = new Library.Model.ExpenseTransaction()
  const myAPI = new Library.WebAPI.ExpenseTransaction()
})
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but didn't have any success.  My Model is undefined.

Comment: Recreated locally, using `requirejs.config({
  bundles: {
    'somedir/CCSEQ.Library': ['CCSEQ/Model', 'CCSEQ/WebAPI']
  }
})

require(['CCSEQ/Model', 'CCSEQ/WebAPI'], function (Model, WebAPI) {
  const myModel = new Model.ExpenseTransaction()
  const myAPI = new WebAPI.ExpenseTransaction()
})`

correctly loads your modules form the single file, but there is error within the module itself, as your typescript isn't importing `ModelBase ` or `APIBase`